# Drag and Drop between Two lists (List 2 only has sort)

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I am struggling to get the required functionality from my current code.

- Two Lists (grid style) List 1 - List 2

  - List 1  items are draggable to list 2, NOT sortable, cloned (but then disabled as you can only add item once)
- List 2 droppable, you can sort, entire item html copies over from list 1.

[Code Pen script](https://codepen.io/ookiemedia/pen/jOqmdaO)

```
 $(function () {
  $('.box').draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});
$("#sortable2").droppable({
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    //add first element when cart is empty
    if ($(this).find('.placeholder').length > 0) {
      $(this).find('.placeholder').remove();
      $("<li></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
    } else {
      //used as flag to find out if element added or not
      var i = 0;
      $(this).children("li").each(function () {
          if ($(this).offset().top >= ui.offset.top) {
            //compare
$("<li class='box'></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).insertBefore($(this));
            i = 1;
            return false; //break loop
          }
        });

      if (i !== 1) {
        //if element dropped at the end of cart
   $("<li class='box'></li>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);
      
      }  
      
    }
  }
})
 $(function() {
  $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "highlight",
        items: "li:not(#sortable1)",
        sort: function () {
     $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
    }
  });
 });
});
 //Display action in text
 $(function DisplayWhatDropped() {
   var area = "Area Dropped";
   var item = "fId of the item";

 $(".result").html(
   "[Action] <b>" + item + "</b>" + " dropped on " + "<b>" + area +   "</b>"
   );
  });
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You wil lwant to use the `connectToSortable` option on your draggable.

Comment: This did help with the ability to sort the items, anywhere in the list.  However, still not sure how to disable or add class to the item in the first list that was dragged over.  I want to eliminate the ability to duplicate in list 2

Comment: You will want to look at the `start` event in Draggable and some of the others in Sortable to add classes. If tyou need more help, please update your post and include your new code and what you have tried.

Comment: @Twisty I have updated the codepen, I don't seem to be triggering any of my alerts or functions when dragging and dropping.  I believe I may be mixing JQuery and Javascript syntax.  added comments also.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911002/jquery-drag-drop-one-list-with-sortable-and-other-list-with-draggable-droppa/60956426#60956426